# only one row importing from csv to mysql table in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying import records from CSV file to MySQL table but only first row inserted. remaining not uploading to database

```
if (isset($_POST["upload_csv"])) {

    $fileName = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

    if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0) {

        $file = fopen($fileName, "r");

        while (($column = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $sqlInsert = "INSERT into price_dump (`stock_id`,`stock_price`,`previous_price`,`minute_set`)
                   values ('" . $column[0] . "','" . $column[1] . "','" . $column[2] . "','" . $column[3] . "')";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlInsert);

            if (! empty($result)) {
                $type = "success";
                $message = "CSV Data Imported into the Database";
            } else {
                $type = "error";
                $message = "Problem in Importing CSV Data";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So DEBUG. Comment out all your sql insert lines, and just do an `echo` statement. Are you seeing each line? This is horrible code, prone to sql injection and hacking. I highly recommend checking out how to prevent against SQL injection and BIND your variables to your query instead.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (isset($_POST["upload_csv"])) {

    $fileName = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

    if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0) {

        $file = fopen($fileName, "r");
        $lines = file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);

        foreach ($lines as $line) {
            $column = explode(',', $line);
            $sqlInsert = "INSERT into price_dump (`stock_id`,`stock_price`,`previous_price`,`minute_set`)
                   values ('" . $column[0] . "','" . $column[1] . "','" . $column[2] . "','" . $column[3] . "')";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlInsert);

            if (! empty($result)) {
                $type = "success";
                $message = "CSV Data Imported into the Database";
            } else {
                $type = "error";
                $message = "Problem in Importing CSV Data";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and maybe csv file separated by ;